# How to stop calling d3.brush if I have keydown ? d3/js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Here is my brush call

```
brush.call(d3.svg.brush() //-calling the brush
        .x(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, width]))
        .y(d3.scale.identity().domain([0, height]))
        .on("brushstart", function(d) {
        d3.selectAll(".selectedNode text")
        .attr("class", "hidden")
        ;
          nodes.each(function(d) { d.previouslySelected = shiftKey && d.selected; });
        })
        .on("brush", function() {

         //console.log(d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey + "ctrl key");

          nodes.classed("selectedNode", function(d) {
            return d.selected = d.previouslySelected ^
                (extent[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < extent[1][0]
                && extent[0][1] <= d.y && d.y < extent[1][1]);
          });
        })
        .on("brushend", function() {
          d3.event.target.clear();
          d3.select(this).call(d3.event.target);
        }));
```

How do I stop calling this on drag if I have, say, the ctrl key down ? So I can then call the zoom function if ctrl key is down which separates the brush and zoom functions

Answer (score 2):

Managed to figure this one out, just wrap the brushstart in a condition :

```
if(!d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey) //-if the ctrl key is not pressed
        { 

}
```

This basically says if the ctrlKey is not down carry on :)

So instead of this :

```
.on("brush", function() {

         //console.log(d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey + "ctrl key");

          nodes.classed("selectedNode", function(d) {
            return d.selected = d.previouslySelected ^
                (extent[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < extent[1][0]
                && extent[0][1] <= d.y && d.y < extent[1][1]);
          });
        })
```

You would have this :

```
.on("brush", function() {

         //console.log(d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey + "ctrl key");
if(!d3.event.sourceEvent.ctrlKey) //-if the ctrl key is not pressed
            { 
          nodes.classed("selectedNode", function(d) {
            return d.selected = d.previouslySelected ^
                (extent[0][0] <= d.x && d.x < extent[1][0]
                && extent[0][1] <= d.y && d.y < extent[1][1]);
          });
}
        })
```